How can I create a valid "request" in Streamlit when trying to utilize SSO with OneLogin to authenticate a user?
I am developing a Streamlit application, but I'd like to manage users using my existing OneLogin SSO. I am focusing on this repository's guides, and have successfully setup the flask demo with OneLogin.
Now that I'm trying to integrate these pieces into Streamlit, I'm having some trouble creating the correct "request" object that comes by default in django/flask.
For example, the repository mentions this flask request object that is passed to OneLogin_Saml2_Auth()
def prepare_from_flask_request(request):
    url_data = urlparse(request.url)
    return {
        'http_host': request.host,
        'server_port': url_data.port,
        'script_name': request.path,
        'get_data': request.args.copy(),
        'post_data': request.form.copy()
    }

In this manner:
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    print(request)
    req = prepare_flask_request(request)
    print(req)
    auth = init_saml_auth(req)

However, this decorator structure doesn't really exist for Streamlit. I imagine I could use the requests package to initiate this get/post request but I'm not sure how to format that into Streamlit or where I would even be making such a request.
My Streamlit app looks like this right now:
import streamlit as st
import os
import requests

from onelogin.saml2.auth import OneLogin_Saml2_Auth
from onelogin.saml2.settings import OneLogin_Saml2_Settings
from onelogin.saml2.utils import OneLogin_Saml2_Utils

req = {
    "https": "off",
    "http_host": "127.0.0.1:8501",
    "script_name": "/",
    "get_data": "",
    "post_data": "",
}

saml_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "saml")

settings = OneLogin_Saml2_Settings(custom_base_path=saml_folder)
auth = OneLogin_Saml2_Auth(req, settings)

if "samlUserdata" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["samlUserdata"] = None

if st.button("login"):
    auth.process_response()
    errors = auth.get_errors()
    if not errors:
        if auth.is_authenticated():
            st.session_state["samlUserdata"] = auth.get_attributes()
            for attr_name in st.session_state["samlUserdata"].keys():
                st.write(
                    f"""{attr_name} ==> \
                    {"|| ".join(st.session_state["samlUserdata"][attr_name]),}"""
                )
        else:
            st.write("Not authenticated")
    else:
        st.write(f"Error when processing SAML Response {', '.join(errors)}")


And when I try the "login" button I get in response SAML Response not found, Only supported HTTP_POST Binding, which I am imagining the POST request to my IdP OneLogin isn't really going to plan.
How can I set up the requests correctly inside Streamlit to get users logged into and retrieve their attributes? I could detail my settings files too, but they pretty much follow the suggestions in the repo I mention above.
